# document.onreadystatechange is HTML 5 or not?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, mozilla, onreadystatechange

i am a bit lost track with the MDN docs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/readystatechange

In the above `onreadystatechange` specification, it says "HTML5". So does it mean `onreadystatechange` is a HTML5 event, and pre-HTML5 browsers should ***not*** understand it? However, i have tested in IE6 (through IE Tester), it works like in my latest Firefox.

So it is confusing. Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: Large parts of HTML5 APIs are only the specification of stuff that was implemented in browsers before already.

Comment: A feature may be part of a particular specification, in this case HTML5, but that's not to say it hasn't been implemented already in older browsers. In fact, most features make it into a spec precisely because they are already popular in various browsers.

Comment: Did you read the page you're linking to ? "This event has long been supported by Internet Explorer ...."

Comment: @adeneo Oh yes! ... Yup i read that. But that was still confusing to me. I think the answer is, as @ Graham says, specifications & features are not having some strict relationships...